# Why isn't it highlighting at the right number?

Tags: jquery

Ive got a quantity box on my product page that when you increase or decrease the quanity a box will highlight what discount you get but for some reason it highlights 3 pack ors more when its on 4 even tho ive got my calculation to highlight when the quantity is >= 3

my code:

```
           //QUANTITY BUTTONS
    var upBtn = jQuery('#btn-qty-up');
    var downBtn = jQuery('#btn-qty-down');
    var currentQty = document.getElementById('qty_extention'); 

    var priceTable = jQuery('#multibuy table');

    var qty = currentQty.value; 

    downBtn.click(function(){
        var currentQty = document.getElementById('qty_extention'); 
        var qty = currentQty.value; 
        //console.log(qty);
        //console.log('down');
        if(!isNaN( qty ) && qty > 0 ){
            currentQty.value--;


            //VARIBLES DECLARED
            var newPrice = jQuery('#dynamic_pricing').find('h1');
            var screwinput = jQuery('select#attribute186').find(":selected").text();

            var calPrice;
            var QtyPrice;

            //IF QUANTITY IS MORE THAN X THEN PRICE IS X
            switch(true) {
                case (qty <= 2):
                    QtyPrice = '12.95';
                    priceTable.find('tr:first-child').css('background', 'none');
                    break;
                case (qty >=3 && qty <= 4):
                    QtyPrice = '12.30';
                    priceTable.find('tr:first-child').css('background', '#ccc');
                    priceTable.find('tr:nth-child(2)').css('background', 'none');

                    break;
                case (qty >=5 && qty <= 9):
                    QtyPrice = '11.65';
                    priceTable.find('tr:first-child').css('background', 'none');
                    priceTable.find('tr:nth-child(2)').css('background', '#ccc');
                    priceTable.find('tr:nth-child(3)').css('background', 'none');
                    break;
                case (qty >=10):
                    QtyPrice = '10.95';
                    priceTable.find('tr:nth-child(2)').css('background', 'none');
                    priceTable.find('tr:nth-child(3)').css('background', '#ccc');
                    break;
            }

            jQuery('#qty').val(currentQty.value);

            calPrice = (QtyPrice * currentQty.value);
            newPrice.html('£' + calPrice.toFixed(2));

        }         

       return false;
    });

    upBtn.click(function(){
        var currentQty = document.getElementById('qty_extention'); 
        var qty = currentQty.value; 
        //console.log(qty);
        //console.log('up');
        if( !isNaN( qty )) {
            currentQty.value++;

            //VARIBLES DECLARED
            var newPrice = jQuery('#dynamic_pricing').find('h1');
            var screwinput = jQuery('select#attribute186').find(":selected").text();

            var calPrice;
            var QtyPrice;

            //IF QUANTITY IS MORE THAN X THEN PRICE IS X
            switch(true) {
                case (qty <= 2):
                    QtyPrice = '12.95';
                    priceTable.find('tr:first-child').css('background', 'none');
                    break;
                case (qty >=3 && qty <= 4):
                    QtyPrice = '12.30';
                    priceTable.find('tr:first-child').css('background', '#ccc');
                    priceTable.find('tr:nth-child(2)').css('background', 'none');
                    break;
                case (qty >=5 && qty <= 9):
                    QtyPrice = '11.65';
                    priceTable.find('tr:first-child').css('background', 'none');
                    priceTable.find('tr:nth-child(2)').css('background', '#ccc');
                    priceTable.find('tr:nth-child(3)').css('background', 'none');
                    break;
                case (qty >=10):
                    QtyPrice = '10.95';
                    priceTable.find('tr:nth-child(2)').css('background', 'none');
                    priceTable.find('tr:nth-child(3)').css('background', '#ccc');
                    break;
            }

            jQuery('#qty').val(currentQty.value);

            calPrice = (QtyPrice * currentQty.value);
            newPrice.html('£' + calPrice.toFixed(2));
        }

        return false;
    });
```

here it is in action:

[image]

I may have my calculation a bit off, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seeing as, for `3` it shows `£38,95`, which is undiscounted, but obviously a multiple of the price for three items, it appears that `qty` is updated *after* the switch is executed, but *before* the final price is set. Which event is the switch triggered on?

Comment: Because you only have two options, try `qty === 3 || qty === 4`

Comment: Those are variable assignments, @Darren, and the likely cause here is not that `>=` would be broken in OP's javascript engine. You are introducing errors without solving any.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Thanks - typo - my bad

Comment: Can you share a little bit more code? How does the qty-variable gets assigned? The case-statement looks fine, so I think it must be the varaible. One more way would be to actually get the value of the qty-variable in different stages of the script with console.log(qty); to be really sure that it's value is correct.

Comment: Obviously `qty` hasn't the value you are expecting it to get. We have no idea on which event do you call your snippet (`mousedown`?!). Anyway, your code is prone to error if user direct input value in your `input`. Let's say he types 3, then 11...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete rewrite of my answer now that we've seen your full code.

You are setting `var qty = currentQty.value`, and *after that* you are modifying the value: `currentQty.value--;`

The value of `qty` won't be changed at this point. Either access `currentQty.value` directly in your switch, as you do when calculating the price, or make sure that `qty` is defined after you have modified the value.

I would also point out that you are reproducing great amounts of code here. Refactoring the code that updates the UI to reflect the new quantity would probably have helped you avoid this issue in the first place.

Consider doing something like this:

```
downBtn.click(function(){
    document.getElementById('qty_extention').value--; 
    updatePrice();
});

upBtn.click(function(){
    document.getElementById('qty_extention').value++; 
    updatePrice();
});

function updatePrice() {
    var qty = document.getElementById('qty_extention').value;
    // set both new price and table highlights here according to updated price
}
```

If `#qty_extention` isn't readonly, you should also run `updatePrice` on it's `change` event, in case someone manually enters a new quantity without the use of your buttons.

Comment: The best event would be `input` event. `keyup` won't be fired in most cases

Comment: @A.Wolff: That is absolutely correct, thanks. Edited.

Comment: @A.Wolff: (And only now do I notice that it isn't an `<input type="number"/>` in the image...)

Comment: Cheers works a charm, Looking at my code I took the long way round to achieve this ha